# Youtube Javascript API - playback rate

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube Javascript API, and I want to be able to increase or decrease the playback rate. Everytime I call getAvailablePlaybackRates() , I get [1] only. So when I try setting the playback rate to 2 for example it doesn't work. What should I do to be able to change the playback rate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [getAvailablePlaybackRates()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#getAvailablePlaybackRates):

> The function returns an array of numbers ordered from slowest to
>   fastest playback speed. Even if the player does not support variable
>   playback speeds, the array should always contain at least one value
>   (1).

The AS3 player does not support variable playback speeds, and not all flavors of the HTML5 video player do either. So I assume that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I'm new at this.. how do I specify which player to use.. I mean how do I say I want to use the HTML5 player?

Comment: There's no supported parameter for forcing the HTML5 player. It's a runtime decision based on what the capabilities are of the current browser, and the default is currently AS3 (unless a cookie is set on the browser by opting in a http://youtube.com/html5).